# Angular2. Handle error on start up

Tags: angular

How can I catch start up errors like compilation or DI and show some meaningful message instead of 'loading' word on a blank page?

`Try`/`catch` with `bootstrapModule` works in some cases:

```
try {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
} catch(ex) {
  handle(ex);
}
```

but not in all, e.g check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/f1YkkfYa9S4Re90lGovC?p=preview) plunker.

Comment: in plunker attached it is syntax error, so you must have to make it correct before app run, i dont think so we can handel this PS:- error here is `</re-h2>` is not a component so remove it to make app run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bootstrapModule` function returns a `Promise<NgModuleRef<M>>` so you can go like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```